# Is it possible to use Powershell to make changes to Application Request Routing (ARR) in IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, powershell

I'm working on some scripts to automate deployments.  I use IIS7 ARR to load balance between two servers.

When doing a deployment I take one of the two out of load balancing and my powershell script deploys code to that server so I can test it before making it live.

It would be awesome if the script could also do the work of taking the server out of balance and putting it back in as it would save me having to open another remote desktop connection :)

Is this possible?  If so, anyone have any examples?

Comment: If I had more spare time, I'd try to look into this.  You could ask the IIS forums here: http://forums.iis.net/1154.aspx

Comment: I'm leaving this as a comment so you get a real answer, but a good place to start is a) PowerShell v2's remoting capabilities, and b) the IIS7 cmdlet pack. http://blogs.iis.net/mailant/archive/2009/01/11/iis7-in-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: never got around to it, working at a Rails shop now so I don't see myself revisiting this :P

Answer (score 17):

To enable **ARR proxy** using Powershell, just run the following...

#### Application Request Routing - Enable Proxy

```cs
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.webServer/proxy" -name "enabled" -value "True"
```

To modify ARR, just use **Configuration Editor** in **IIS Manager** and click **Generate Script** under the Actions menu.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used this snippet to disabled caching on an ARR server farm:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/webFarms/webFarm[@name="MyServerFarm"]/applicationRequestRouting/protocol/cache' -Name enabled -Value $false
```

So in theory you could take a server out of the farm like this:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter '/webFarms/webFarm[@name="MyServerFarm"]/server[@address="server1.domain.com"]' -Name enabled -Value $false
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post but all the ARR and rewrite stuff is configured via web/apphost.config so you can use the iis(8) config editor to make/view changes, and also generate scripts (generate script - on the left side, you need to make a change for it to become enabled)

This page on technet is also useful as a reference
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee683953(v=ws.10).aspx